# Supress Enable Macros event when opening a file via Application.GetOpenFilename

Tags: excel, vba

I tried searching about this a lot over google but of no use, i want to open a file via Application.GetOpenFilename function and copy & paste a bit from source file to target file but every time i open it up it throws a pop-up to enable/disable macros.

I have tried

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.EnableEvents = False

everywhere in the code, it helps in suppressing all other events but not the Enable Macros event.

Following is my code:

```
Sub Browse_WeeklyFile()
Dim strFileToOpen As String
Dim Wbk_WeeklyTemplate As Workbook
Dim Tgt_ShtNm As String
Dim Src_ShtNm As String

'Choosing an Excel File using File dialog Box and capturing the file path in the variable
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select the latest Weekly template to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsm (*.xlsm),", MultiSelect:=False)

'Checking if file is selected
If strFileToOpen = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set Wbk_WeeklyTemplate = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpen)
End If

''Refer sheet by Sheet CodeName
Src_ShtNm = SheetName(Wbk_WeeklyTemplate, "Sht_FactoryDetails")
Tgt_ShtNm = SheetName(ThisWorkbook, "Sht_Ref")

Wbk_WeeklyTemplate.Sheets(Src_ShtNm).Range("N15:X18").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Tgt_ShtNm).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Wbk_WeeklyTemplate.Close

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Is there any way to make the new file read only or suppress the enable macro events.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

PS: SheetName is a user defined function here to refer the sheet name by sheet code name.

Comment: This one may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837822.aspx

Comment: @Prisoner:  Amazing that's really what i needed, thanks a lot man :)